# Inject properties into object which is not a spring managed bean

Tags: spring, properties, static, inversion-of-control

I have a spring application where in some cases I need to create an object at runtime, as opposed to a spring injected bean. This object should be created with properties that come from the application context however. If this object is not spring-injected, how can I still take advantage of IoC? Should I make these object properties static and inject them into a bean via non-static setters?

Comment: are you sure you can't use spring to fulfill that runtime dependency? like using a factory method?

Comment: @leeor In other words, create a factory bean with the IoC properties, which would then create the concrete object at runtime with those properties from the factory? I suppose that's one option.

Answer (score 0):

You can still inject properties for object which is not created by spring. 
To do that you should use @Configurable annotation. And you should enable LoadTimeWeaving or CompileTimeWeaving. But I think that can be overkill for your situation.